# "commit suicide" In A Literary Way

Tags: expressions, literary-techniques

> They have committed suicide.

It sounds too cold. I am not writing a report.

> They have ended their lives.

It sounds too boring.

---

So how can I phrase it such that there is a sense of beauty?

Comment: You’re not the first to grapple with this question. There is a classic scene in literature about this. Here it is: “Is that how one says it? As simply as that? “Mark Antony is dead. Lord Antony is dead.” “The soup is hot; the soup is cold.” “Mark Antony is living; Mark Antony is dead.” Shake with terror when such words pass your lips … ” Here’s the link to where this reference is used, just as you would like to use it: http://billcainonline.com/?p=2170

Comment: Rather than closing this question, I think it should be migrated to [Writers](http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions).  (I'd do that myself, if I had the permissions and the know-how...)

Comment: Please stop migrating these to Writers; these single-phrase questions with no context will simply be closed, pending further edits to provide context and specific questions about the excerpt.

Comment: Hmmm... okay... if you say so... @ArchJ - maybe try Yahoo! answers, or Answerbag.com... Evidently, this question doesn't have a home on the StackExchange.  Too bad, I thought it was a decent question...

Comment: and @HexagonTiling Thanks for the link! It's inspirational.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> They chose to take their own lives

maybe, or

> They chose to depart from this life to the next.

I think the key is the choice of verb - 'have' is quite passive-sounding, whereas a more action-based verb like 'choose' or 'take' might be more to your liking.

Answer (score 5):

[In the words of Don McLean](http://www.lyrics007.com/Don%20McLean%20Lyrics/Vincent%20Lyrics.html):

> *You took your life as lovers often do* 
>   *But I could have told you, Vincent* 
>   *This world was never meant* 
>   *For one as beautiful as you*

Comment: precisely the lyric that I was thinking of, so +1 for you!

Answer (score 3):

They have elected total abstinence.

Comment: made me smirk :) +1

Answer (score 1):

They have entered eternity without waiting to be invited.

Answer (score 0):

They have made final transition ahead of schedule.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the writing to be more vivid, add more details. Explain how and why they did it. If this is fiction, then add details about the location, what they were wearing, how it sounded, smelled, looked, etc.